# active directory with xamarin method

Tags: xamarin, active-directory, ldap

I wrote the following code to find out if the user logging has an account at active directory so i may allow him to proceed and it's working fine:

```
public bool AuthenticateUser(string domain, string username, string password, string LdapPath)
        {
            string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LdapPath, domainAndUsername, password);
            try
            {
                // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
                Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                if (null == result)
                {
                    return false;
                }
```

and it works great, the only problem is that i need to make the same thing using xamarin forms , how may I?

Answer (score 0):

DirectorySearcher is a class that you would use from a server API/code.

I suggest you to create a Web API that would do the same job and that will be called by your Xamarin application.